# How to use customized onClick in data binding?

Tags: android, data-binding, onclicklistener, android-databinding

I am using data binding and having trouble solving multiple quick click. I do not want to put a logic in every click instead, I want to create a solution once and expect it to work throughout my project.

I found one solution [here](https://medium.com/@simonkarmy2004/solving-android-multiple-clicks-problem-kotlin-b99c06135da0). Code snippet from that page is as follows:

```
class SafeClickListener(
        private var defaultInterval: Int = 1000,
        private val onSafeCLick: (View) -> Unit
) : View.OnClickListener {
    private var lastTimeClicked: Long = 0
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTimeClicked < defaultInterval) {
            return
        }
        lastTimeClicked = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        onSafeCLick(v)
    }
}
```

And using extension funciton:

```
fun View.setSafeOnClickListener(onSafeClick: (View) -> Unit) {
    val safeClickListener = SafeClickListener {
        onSafeClick(it)
    }
    setOnClickListener(safeClickListener)
}
```

Now, for any view we can simply call:

```
anyView.setSafeOnClickListener {
    doYourStuff()
}
```

Which is awesome. But it only applies if I am calling `setOnClickListener` to a view but I am using data binding. Where I am using something like this:

```
android: onClick="@{(view) -> myViewModel.UIEvents(SomeUIEvent.showDialog)}"
```

I am aware that if I can create a binding adapter, I would be able to solve the problem. But, I couldn't make one that works.

How can I achieve something that I can use with data binding and that works globally like the above example?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use @BindingAdapter.